# Socket.io - different maxHttpBufferSize values depending on the nature of the request

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I am creating an application that allows users to submit JSON or Base64 image data via socket.io

The goal I am trying to achieve is:

- if JSON is submitted, the message can have a maximum size of 1MB
- if a Base64 image is submitted, the message can have a maximum size of 5MB

From the socket.io docs I can see that:

- you can specify a *maxHttpBufferSize* option value that allows you to limit the maximum message size
- namespaces allow you to split logic over a single connection

However, I can't figure out the correct way to get the functionality to work the way I have described above.

Would I need to:

1. set up 2 separate io instances on the server, one for JSON data and the other for Base64 images (therefore allowing me to set separate *maxHttpBufferSize* values for each), and then the client can use the correct  instance, depending on what they want to submit (if so, what is the correct way of doing this?)
2. set up 1 instance with a *maxHttpBufferSize* of 5MB, and then add in my own custom logic to determine message sizes and prevent further actions if the data is JSON and over 1MB in size
3. set this up in some totally different way that I haven't thought of

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the API, `maxHttpBufferSize` is a parameter for the underlying Engine.IO server (of which there is one instance per Socket.IO Server Instance). Obviously you're free to set up two servers but I doubt it makes sense to separate the system into two entirely different applications.

Talk of using Namespaces to separate logic is more about handling different messages at different endpoints (for example you would register a `removeUserFromChat` message handler to a user connecting via an `/admin` namespace, but you wouldn't want to register this to a user connecting via the `/user` namespace).

In the most recent socket server I set up, I defined my own protocol where part of the response would contain a HTTP status code, as well as a description that could be displayed to the user. For example I would return `200` on success. If I was uploading a file via a REST HTTP Interface, I would expect a `400` (BAD REQUEST) response if my request couldn't be processed - and I believe that this makes sense for your use case. Alternatively you could define your own custom `4XX` error code if the file is too large, and handle this in your UI purely based on the code returned. Obviously you don't need to follow the HTTP protocol, and the design decisions are ultimately up to you, but in my opinion it makes sense to return some kind of error response in your message handler.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `maxHttpBufferSize` has different use at lower levels than your use case. When sending content over network, content is split into 'n bytes' of packets and when a application writes 'n' bytes, the network sends a packet over network (the less the n, more overhead due to network headers. The more the n, high latency because of waiting involved in accumulating n bytes before sending). Documentation is not clear about `maxHttpBufferSize` but it could be the packet size (n) configuration, not limit on the max data on connection.

It seems, http request header `Content-Length` might serve your purpose. It gives the actual object size based on that you can make a decision.